# Issue with login customer create backend

Tags: login, backend, customer-account

I'm new here and I hope the community is able to help me out on starting with magento.

The issue I have is that the customer created via backend can't loging, while the frontend created user can.
I tried registering the same account via forntend and I receive a message that this profile already exists, meaning that the system acknoledge that customer created via backend.
I changed in phpmyadmin the ucustomer_entity website_id and is_active to the same specifics as the working customer. Saidly no effect.

Could anybody help me out about what would be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SE, please provide as much details as possible about your problem (Magento version, solutions tried...) so the community can help you and your question won't be closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the new customer profile via Magento backend set the option    '**Associate to Website**' to '***Main website***' in place of '**Admin**'.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I changed try to change this in the admin but couldn't change it as it was set (no scroll list).
Anyway, I deleted the customer and added him again an immediate changed Associate to Website to Main website. This worked!

Thanks for helping me out Alain!